How to send command to a program run with bash in rust
I'm running a java minecraft server through bash with rust and need to input /stop into the java server, I'm new to rust and this is the first program I've written.
Also running the program stops all input, is it possible to make it run in the background and type /stop in the terminal to stop it when needed.
let command = format!("cd ./servers/{server_name}/ && ../../jdk/{java_version}/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar ../../profiles/{minecraft_version} nogui");
    println!("{command}");
    let _output = Command::new("/bin/sh")
        .args(["-c", &command])
        .output()
        .expect("error");

This code runs the server but I can only stop it with Ctrl+C in the terminal.

Note that running the target process in a shell is redundant. You may just set the current_dir of the Command and pass the JVM as process and its args directly to the subprocess.

You can do this with cargo's the command's stdin, which you can access if you change .output() to .spawn()

    // Start your server
    let command = format!("cd ./servers/{SEVER_NAME}/ && ../../jdk/{JAVA_VERSION}/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar ../../profiles/{MINECRAFT_VERSION} nogui");
    println!("{command}");
    let mut child = Command::new("/bin/sh")
        .args(["-c", &command])
        .spawn() // <-- spawn process
        .unwrap();

    // Do whatever waiting you need
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)); // 2-second delay

    // Provide input to the command via STDIN
    if let Some(ref mut stdin) = child.stdin {
        stdin
            .write_all(b"your_input_here\n")
            .expect("Failed to write to stdin");
    }

    // Wait for the command to finish
    let output = child
        .wait_with_output()
        .expect("Failed to wait on child");

